# How to shift timestamps in multiple sequential file names (wav files, from bioacoustic monitoring) using R

Tags: files, r

I deployed passive acoustic recorders to detect animal calls but on one of my devices the date & time settings got messed up and reverted to the default (Jan 1, 2000). And then the device recorded for a month, writing 20-min files that are day & time stamped. e.g., file name is swift1_20000101_020000.wav (deviceName_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS). And now I reeeeally don't want to have to manually rename 2000+ individual files.

I know the actual start date & time from my field notes and I'm wondering if there's a way to input that actual start date/time and have all the files shift off of that. So swift1_20000101_000000 would become swift1_20220617_093000, swift1_20000101_002000 would become swift1_20220617_095000, and so on in some sort of loop.

Any ideas? I know you can rename files with file.rename(), paste0(), etc but I would need a function that iterated on all files within the directory sequentially and I haven't been able to find something that will do it. Any thoughts or ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Selene Fregosi told me to post it here

Comment: @Thejasvi While you could argue that this question is better suited for a different platform, I think this is a very common problem in bioacoustic data logging and if this site is going to be the leader for bioacoustic-related questions, I would argue that it is an appropriate question to ask here.

Comment: Have deleted my comments seeing the discussion at the Meta play out! There is indeed sense in having field-specidic programming questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a common problem and we run into it often.  I have mocked up some example R code to show how you can handle this problem in R as described. You can also build a new folder structure and use this (or similar) code to reorganize files.

```
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(fs)
library(dplyr)

# set deployment date/time
datetime_deployment= ymd_hms("20220617_093000")

# list all the files that need to be changed
# files<-dir_ls("path/to/files",glob = "*wav")

files<-c("path/to/file/swift1_20000101_020000.wav",
         "path/to/file/swift1_20000101_022000.wav")

# We will use this data frame for organizing the new paths to which 
# we will rename your files
dat<-data.frame(path=files,
                filename=basename(files)) %>%
    mutate(
        # extract the file datetimes
        datetime=ymd_hms(str_extract(filename,"[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{6}")),
        # find the difference between your files and the deployment datetime
        diff=datetime_deployment-datetime,
        # add the max of the differences to the file date time (this
        # assumes that the deployment datetime is after all
        # of the file datetimes)
        datetime_new=datetime+max(diff),
        # extract the sensor_name from the filename (for your usecase
        # this regex is way overkill but it works for other
        # prefixes and datetime formats)
        sensor_name=str_extract(filename,
             '^.*?(?=((_D[0-9]{8}(\\([0-9]\\)|_))?(_|-)?D?[0-9]{8}(T|_)[0-9]{6}))'),
        # get the file extention (useful if you have more than 1)
        file_ext=path_ext(path),
        # build new path
        new_path=file.path(dirname(path),
                           paste0(sensor_name,"_",
                                  format(datetime_new, 
                                         "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"),".", 
                                         file_ext)))

# check for duplicates and fix if there are, otherwise you will
# overwrite them when you move
dat %>% 
    group_by(new_path) %>%
    tally %>% 
    filter(n>1)

# you can copy the files (will not change the originals) or you can
# move the files (the originals disappear).  Use copy=TRUE
# if you are unsure if you have the correct paths and want to be able
# to go back to the originals
copy = TRUE


if(copy==TRUE){
    # slow and you will get a copy of the file (but it is safe if you
    # have any mistakes in the new path you will still have
    # the old data)
    file_copy(dat$path,dat$new_path, overwrite = F)
}else{
    # WAY faster but distructive (essentially will rename the files)
    file_move(dat$path,dat$new_path)
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!! Will give this go and report back...

Comment: @CarlyBatist did this code work to solve your problem?